# I have a NVIDIA GeForce graphics card as well as an integrated Intel HD graphics card

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have a NVIDIA GeForce graphics card as well as an integrated Intel HD graphics card. I know that by default NVIDIA is disabled, so I switched the setting on most of my programs to use NVIDIA however whenever I change it for Chrome it still uses Intel. I tried changing the GPU back and forth couple time, but nothing worked.
I am using MSI GP62 7RD Leopard Laptop with Intel i7. My integrated GPU is Intel HD Graphics 630 and I also have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050.

Comment: Can you provide with more information? Are you using laptop (and Optimus solution) or a PC?

Comment: go to `chrome://gpu/` and scroll down to the table and find the entry that says `GL_RENDERER`. What does your value say there?